# How to make the collage portrate with several pictures in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I means, I want create collage portrate from my portrate photo in photoshop soft ware with my other portrate photos.

Excuse me, I'm persian; so I can't speak very well!

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new document
2. Open your existing photo in Photoshop
3. In the Layers palette, right click on the background layer
4. Select "duplicate layer"
5. Select your new document as the target for the duplicate layer
6. return to the new document; your photo will show up as a new layer; use transform tools to resize and reposition as desired.
7. Repeat steps 2 through 6 to add additional photos to the collage.

The key here is to put each photo on a separate layer, so you can transform each on individually.

Hope that helps.